# Expected identifier or '('

Tags: objective-c

Trying to write simple program on Fraction operations. 
Can't compile the code. Getting an "expected identifier or '(' xcode" error in the interface around "subtract" method.

I did a research on that problem and it seems to me that it's some sort of generic error.
Here is my program:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
// Define the Fraction class
@interface Fraction : NSObject
{
int numerator;
int denominator;
}
@property int numerator, denominator;
-(void) print;
-(void) setTo: (int) n over: (int) d;
 -(double) convertToNum;
-(Fraction *) add: (Fraction *) f;
–(Fraction *) subtract: (Fraction *) f;
–(Fraction *) multiply: (Fraction *) f;
–(Fraction *) divide: (Fraction *) f;

-(void) reduce; 
@end

#import "Fraction.h"
@implementation Fraction
@synthesize numerator, denominator;
-(void) print
{
NSLog (@"%i/%i", numerator, denominator);
}
-(double) convertToNum
{
if (denominator != 0)
return (double) numerator / denominator;
else
    return NAN;
}
-(void) setTo: (int) n over: (int) d
{
numerator = n;
denominator = d;
}
// add a Fraction to the receiver

-(Fraction *) add: (Fraction *) f
{

Fraction *result = [[Fraction alloc] init];
result.numerator = numerator * f.denominator +
denominator * f.numerator;
result.denominator = denominator * f.denominator;
[result reduce];
return result;
}

-(Fraction *) subtract: (Fraction *) f
{
Fraction *result = [[Fraction alloc] init];
result.numerator = numerator * f.denominator -
denominator * f.numerator;
result.denominator = denominator * f.denominator;
[result reduce];
return result;
}

-(Fraction *) multiply: (Fraction *) f
{
Fraction *result= [[Fraction alloc] init];

result.numerator = numerator * f.numerator;
result.denominator = denominator * f.denominator;
[result reduce];
return result;

}


-(Fraction *) divide: (Fraction *) f;
{
Fraction *result = [[Fraction alloc] init];
result.numerator= numerator * f.denominator;
result.denominator = denominator * f.numerator;
[result reduce];
return result;
}

-(void) reduce
{
int u = numerator;
int v = denominator;
int temp;
while (v != 0) {
temp = u % v;
u = v;
v = temp;
}
numerator /= u;
denominator /= u;
}
@end
#import "Fraction.h"

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
NSAutoreleasePool * pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];


Fraction *myFraction1 = [[Fraction alloc] init];
Fraction *myFraction2 = [[Fraction alloc] init];


[myFraction2 setTo:200 over:300];

[myFraction1 setTo: 100 over: 300];




[myFraction2 subtract: myFraction1];


NSLog (@"The value of myFraction2 is:");

[myFraction2 print];

[myFraction2 release];
[myFraction1 release];

[pool drain];
return 0;
}
```

Comment: dude, do you have a line number?

Comment: Xcode->Preferences->Text Editing->Show: Line numbers

Comment: Awesome Caleb! but would numbers also copy when i copy lines of code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the comma at the end of this line in `main`:

```
Fraction *myFraction2 = [[Fraction alloc] init], ;
```

Comment: Removed. (from original post too). Now program compiles but has breakpoint in the implementation section in the "subtract" method definition. Any ideas?

Comment: No, you haven't yet removed the stray comma from the original post.

Comment: Done! (it's just i have interface, implementation and main as different files). Still have "breakpoint" though. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that's a literal copy and paste, you've used the wrong dash. At last on the UK and US keyboard the one you want is on the right hand side of the '0' key. You appear to be using an en-dash. If you look very closely at your listing above, particularly `add:` versus `subtract:` in the list at the top, you'll see that your character is very slightly wider.

Try copying and pasting this:

```
-(Fraction *) subtract: (Fraction *) f;
```

Over your existing definition to see the difference.

Comment: Replaced. (from original post too). Now program compiles but has breakpoint in the implementation section in the "subtract" method definition. Any ideas?

Comment: As in a breakpoint you've inadvertently set yourself — making it an Xcode usage question — or an exception is being raised and invoking the debugger?

Comment: I'm sorry i didn't get last comment...